# Unable to configure php on apache2 httpd server. Unable to find php modules where .so file is located

Tags: php, apache2, rhel7

Unable to configure php on apache2 httpd server. Unable to find php modules where .so file is located.

I am using rhel7:apache2 image and then installing php and php-common packages.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

## rpm -ql php

it has 
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tried... It worked.. i found it on some different directory. Not sure what was the issue.. on recreating pod it worked fine..

Thanks